# Can one make clang-tidy fail on invalid configuration?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Whenever clang-tidy finds an error in my code, it also warns me that there's an invalid configuration value in my `.clang-tidy` file:

> warning: invalid configuration value '' for option 'readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase'

That is indeed an error, which I intend to fix.

I would however like if I could make clang-tidy fail when there's something wrong in my configuration, instead of just warning about it and continuing. It's extra bad since these warnings are only printed whenever clang-tidy finds an error in my code. So I won't notice until that happens.

Is there a way to ask clang-tidy to fail hard for configuration errors?

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this and had no good clang-tidy errors for a month. :vomit.

Our fix is to add `clang-tidy --verify-config` in our build pipeline. Since on failure it still says `No config errors detected.` and return 0, we look at stderr.

If you use cmake, it could look like this:

```
  find_program(BASH bash HINTS /bin)
  message("stderr=\`${CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY} --verify-config\`")
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET <whatever target you care about>
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env ${BASH} -c "stderr=\`${CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY} --verify-config 2\>&1 >/dev/null \`; echo \"Validating clang-tidy; testing if $stderr is empty\"; test -z \"$stderr\""
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/<where you want to verify config>
# Provides correct escaping for the command.
    VERBATIM
  )
```

Comment: That's... not nice, haha! It's a clever workaround though, so thanks! I wish it was possible to solve this in a better way.